# How to redirect stdout to both a file and `sys.__stdout__`?

Tags: python, file, stdout

The following lines change the `stdout` from `sys.__stdout__` to a file. This works fine.

```
import sys
sys.stdout = open("stdout.txt", "a")
print("test")
```

However, I want the output to the file as well as to `sys.__stdout__`. What do I need to add so `"test"` will be written to both?

Comment: If you're on a unix system, pipe stdout to __tee__ and it will take care of it for you.

Comment: Be wary of replacing standard output like this. The whole point is that it is a file handle specified by the *user* of your program; you are just writing to the file requested by the user. If you want to write to a different file, be explicit: use the `file` argument to `print` to direct output to a specific file.

Comment: @emmi474 yes, outside of python, on the command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make your own file-like object whose `write` method sends the data to both places and install it as `sys.stdout`.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to "intercept" calls to `sys.stdout.write` with a `mock_write` function which writes the text to a file and calls the original `real_write` function, afterwards.

```py
import sys

def mock_write(text):
    with open("test.txt", "a") as fh:
        fh.write(text)
    real_write = type(sys.stdout).write
    real_write(sys.stdout, text)

sys.stdout.write = mock_write
print("TEST")
```

It's rather unlikely, but this solution might stop working with future versions of Python in case the original `write` method of `sys.stdout` is changed and becomes incompatible with our mock function.

Also, some functions, like `subprocess.Popen` for example, don't use `sys.stdout.write` but directly write to the `fileno` file descriptor of a file object. So the mock write won't catch that output.

By the way, this approach of replacing existing methods of an object with another function has its limits: For instance, it won't work with magic methods and `__slots__`. See [Adding a Method to an Existing Object Instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/972/adding-a-method-to-an-existing-object-instance) for example, for further reading.

Comment: About my edit: since you don’t need `self` in `mock_write` (because it’s hidden in `real_write`), we can make `sys.stdout.write` be a normal function-valued attribute rather than a method.  You could also avoid `real_write` by calling `type(sys.stdout).write(sys.stdout,text)`.

Comment: They *become* normal functions on lookup, just like normal functions (and `classmethod` objects) become method objects.

Comment: For reference: it fails with magic methods because of [how they are looked up](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-lookup).  `__slots__` prevents assignments it doesn’t mention, and a [non-data descriptor](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#invoking-descriptors) can prevent reading an instance attribute entirely.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this to keep it simple and avoid modifying `sys.stdout`:

```
import sys

my_log = open('log.txt', 'a')

def write_out(data):
    print(data, file=sys.stdout)
    my_log.write(data + '\n')

def write_err(data):
    print(data, file=sys.stderr)
    my_log.write(data + '\n')

def main():
    write_out('test out')
    write_err('test err')
```

Comment: That only works if you control all the output code.  Of course, if this was an XY issue, that might be just right.

Comment: @emmi474 You could have variations of `write_out` and `write_err`.

Comment: That's true. If you want _all_ stdout and _all_ stderr to go to your log file no matter what, you'll have to do something like what @DavisHerring suggested.

Comment: @Wyatt: The [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/): the OP might really have wanted to duplicate just their own functions’ output.  (They since said otherwise.)